# Extended Kalman Filter formulation

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filters

For a nonlinear system,
$$
\begin{align}
&{\boldsymbol x}(k+1)={\boldsymbol f}({\boldsymbol x}(k),{\boldsymbol u}(k),{\boldsymbol w}(k)) \\
&{\boldsymbol y}(k)={\boldsymbol h}({\boldsymbol x}(k),{\boldsymbol v}(k))
\end{align}
$$

I would like to find the Extended Kalman Filter (EKF), having a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter), I have reached

$$
\begin{align}
& \hat {\boldsymbol x}(k+1|k)={\boldsymbol f}(\hat {\boldsymbol x}(k|k),{\boldsymbol u}(k|k)) \\
& {\boldsymbol P}(k+1|k)={\boldsymbol F}(k){\boldsymbol P}(k|k){\boldsymbol F}^T(k)+{\boldsymbol L}(k) {\boldsymbol Q}(k) {\boldsymbol L}^T(k)
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
&{\boldsymbol S}(k+1)={\boldsymbol H}(k+1){\boldsymbol P}(k+1|k){\boldsymbol H}^T(k+1)+{\boldsymbol M}(k+1){\boldsymbol R}(k+1){\boldsymbol M}^T(k+1) \\
& {\boldsymbol K}(k+1)={\boldsymbol P}(k+1|k) {\boldsymbol H}^T (k+1){\boldsymbol S}^{-1}(k+1) \\
& \hat{\boldsymbol x}(k+1|k+1)=\hat{\boldsymbol x}(k+1|k)+{\boldsymbol K}(k+1)[y(k+1)-{\boldsymbol h}(\hat {\boldsymbol x}(k+1|k))] \\
& {\boldsymbol P}(k+1|k+1)k=[{\boldsymbol I}-{\boldsymbol K}(k+1){\boldsymbol H}(k+1)]{\boldsymbol P}(k+1|k)
\end{align}
$$

where

$$
\begin{align}
& {\boldsymbol F}(k)=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol f}{\partial \boldsymbol x}|_{\hat {\boldsymbol x}(k|k),{\boldsymbol u}(k)} \\
& {\boldsymbol H}(k+1)=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol h}{\partial \boldsymbol x}|_{\hat {\boldsymbol x}(k+1|k)}\\
&{\boldsymbol L}(k)=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol f}{\partial\boldsymbol w}|_{\hat {\boldsymbol x}(k|k),{\boldsymbol u}(k)}\\
&{\boldsymbol M}(k+1)=\frac{\partial\boldsymbol h}{\partial\boldsymbol v}|_{\hat {\boldsymbol x}(k+1|{\color{red}{k+1}})}
\end{align}
$$

Is this obtained formulation correct?

My main concerns are about the whole timing indexes especially the last one.

Comment: Maybe you could give some background what you want to use the EKF for? More often than not your model looks more like $x(k+1)=f(x(k),u(k))+w(k)$ and $y(k)=h(x(k)) +v(k)$ or at least this is a good approximation which yields a much simpler representation of the equations, e.g., in that case $M(k+1)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial v}=I$ no matter what index. The same holds true for L(k) in that case. A very good resource for Kalman Filtering is "Optimal State Estimation: Kalman, H-Infinity, and Nonlinear Approaches." by Simon, D. (2006).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the formulation is correct apart from
$M(k+1)$ which should be
$$M(k+1)=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}_k}{\partial \boldsymbol{v}}\bigg\vert_{\hat{\boldsymbol{x}}(k+1|k)}$$